# Is it possible to to rerun a web-crawler in import.io?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, import.io

My computer shut down in the middle of running the crawler and now I need to rerun it.

Comment: this is literally a yes no question

Comment: I guess I should have put  **and how do I do that if you can re-run a crawler?**

Comment: Hi Colin, Do you mean you want to get the snapshot the data that was captured before the run was cut short of you just want to completely re-run the crawler? Thanks, Meg

Comment: Completely re-run the crawler without training again.

Comment: You simply can click the edit button on your my data page and re-run the crawler.

Comment: Sweet, Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: Happy to help! Feel free to continue this thread if you have an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can click the edit button on your my data page and re-run the crawler.